# Error in Imported .Jar file

Tags: java, jar

[I am facing the error while i didn't import anything in the code. Please assist][1]

[1]:< https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZKp7.jpg >

Comment: is this intellij?

Comment: @UjjwalGulecha Looks like Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Like you use eclipse, and you need more information to help. 
If you don't import anything in the code, i think you need config your app (missing library, not match jdk version, check JRE system library...). You can see error with class DTN2Events.

Comment: Yes the error is in DTN2Events. Also I am looking forward to receive a simple code comprises of 50 nodes with RWP model and Prophet protocol. Can you HELP?